# How can I reset my dropdown-menu when click on other button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown-menu and 2 btns(AP,SP) in the same row.

I chose `Geary, Mia` on the drop-down menu, I want to reset it to **ClassView** when I press on a different btn.

**Note:** ClassView is my default selection.

[image]

---

## HTML

for dropdown-menu

```
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1"> <span>Class View </span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a id="class-view" href="#">Class View</a></li>
        <li><a id="student#1" class="student" href="#">Geary, Mia</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

Below is what I have now :

## [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/utm8k62h/1/)

Any hints ?

Comment: in your $btnStandard.click function, try adding $('#dd').find('span').text('Class View'); and see if it works for u. here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/utm8k62h/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@Sushil** and **@emmaaaah** for get me thinking at the right direction.

I'm sure that there is more than 1 way to accomplish this such task, but here how I did mine. I

---

## Create

a function called : classViewReset()

```
function classViewReset() {
    $student.removeClass('active');
    $classView.removeClass('active');
    $('#dd').find('span').text('Class View');
}
```

---

## Call it back

on all my onClick(); functions.

```
$btnAssignment.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    classViewReset(); //<----------------- Call
    imgLoader({btn: $btnAssignment, }); 
});
```

Now my dropdown-menu is reset properly as I wanted. See it live : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/utm8k62h/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$("#btn-assignment").click(function(){
    $(".dropdown li").eq(0).trigger("click");
});
```

This will trigger 'click' onto the first LI element, which should reselect it

I attached this event to the 'Assignment Performance' button

http://jsfiddle.net/2v57wnys/1/

Comment: It's not meant to do that. I wrote "I attached this event to the 'Assignment Performance' button" so it is only attached to it. http://jsfiddle.net/2v57wnys/2/ if you want both.

Comment: Select the first item of that is selected by the selector query - which is the first LI element here